# How do you generate release notes?

Tags: continuous-integration

**[Question]**
Does anyone product release notes via an automated process? If so how. Especially with continuous integration services. Do you just use a script to parse the log files for issues fixed for that release to create the appropriate text file?

**[Background]**
Recently I have implemented continuous integration for my hobby projects. As part of it I have had issue tracking reporting linked into my builds. However for releases I wish to do the same thing and have it produce a release notes files similar to the nhibernate release notes.txt which I find very clean.

**[Example]**

> ## Build 1.2.1
>
> Bug Fixed:
>
> ```
> * [ID-1] - The system doesn't accept valid usernames
> ```
>
> Improvements:
>
> ```
> * [ID-2] - Saving the file takes 3 minutes when it should take a few seconds.
> ```
>
> New Features:
>
> ```
> * [ID-3] - Allow users to refresh the page using the F5 key.
> ```
>
> Task Completed:
>
> ```
> * [ID-4] - Document undocumented configuration properties.
> ```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generally this sort of thing is done by issue tracking software. You track every new feature, every bugfix and every enhancement, assign them to a release and then generate release notes from the descriptions.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using maven, there is a the [maven changes plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/index.html) for this purpose and producing this report could thus be easily automated in an continuous integration process.

Comment: For exact steps on how to configure the maven changes plugin, you may find this helpful: http://kaviddiss.com/2014/10/28/release_notes_from_jira/

Answer (score 4):

If you use **JIRA (which I'd suggest any way), it can [auto-generate the release notes](https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/bwISCw) for you**. The built-in format is rather simplistic, but works well in many cases. The content is customizable to a point, albeit this is not the ultimate word in terms of flexibility.

If you look for better release notes from JIRA, try the [PDF View Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/5167). It:

- more than just a raw "completed issues" list (ex: installation and upgrade instructions, legal details, executed tests, changed files)
- more control over what is included (excluding certain statuses, resolutions, issue types, etc.)
- allows distributing your Release Notes document in email (PDF format) or printed on paper

*Disclaimer: I'm a a developer of this commercial JIRA add-on.*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am wrestling with the same problems. In our development we use svn/jira and we have a custom tool that will attempt to build and sanity test changes before they are committed - and the develop enters the jira number as part of that process (it validates the number). This jira number is then included in the SVN commit

From then we generate a release note between two points in svn and from the comments on each commit can build a list of issues that have been committed and populate the release note.

The problem with this is that 1. issues in the release note need to be entered as code changes. Issues fixed without a code change are not included. 2. If a developer is half way through a fix it will appear in the release notes when may it should not.

I want to find a solution with minimal manual overhead where we can take any build from our CI system and turn it into a release.

I am considering adapting the process so that the release note generate will fail if a issue is not closed - but feel the developers will complain that they might be half way though an issue when we want to make a release.

The other option is to only include completed issues in the release note. However the problem with that is that if a developer make a fix in release A but did not close the issue at the time A was release - and then made no code changes and closed the issue after A was released how do I now automatically include this issue in the release notes (May be I could search all jiras closed between release A and B....)

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

In my company we use bugzilla.  We use the milestone to tag a bug with a specific release number.  Then we generate an xml report for all the bugs with a specific milestone and we use a small script to generate the release notes out of it.

This is something that can be easily generalized to any bug tracking software, in general.

I guess it could also be tied to comments in the commit messages on your version control system.  A query could be made to list all comments on the commits on verson control and then filter for all of the comments with a specific tag.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the developers are not privateers and are part of a team that gets assignments and does them, a list of what was done and should be part of UAT is the defacto release note. Lists of file changes and the like are irrelevant and can be trivially extracted from source control.

Since it is painfully hard to enforce a policy of developers checking in code with issue numbers in it, I don't bother. I ask about it at the code review. I also keep a list of what we are working on. The stuff that is done-done gets added to the log right before the mvn release:prepare commands are run. I then walk it over to the QA and UAT.

This is not likely to scale to hundreds of issues per week. In those cases, a more robust system is likely to be preferable.

Comment: @sal: I'm trying this privately to convince my work place to do it. Which would mean I would be transferring this to a different system. You are right about forcing developers to check in issue numbers. Personally I do it to all my check ins but people tend not to like to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like doxygen to do this, but it's kind of tedious to comment the way doxygen expects.  I usually get these by hand.

Not sure, but wouldn't something like FogBugz also do this?

Answer (score 0):

For those working with .NET and TFS, you could use [TfsChangeLog](http://tfschangelog.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Generating%20Release%20Notes%20Report) to automatically generate your release notes.

> TFS ChangeLog allows Team Foundation Server (TFS) users to extract information related to Changesets and associated WorkItems into XML format that is transformed into HTML. 
>   TFSChangeLog automatically produces Change Log / Release Notes based on selected changeset range.
>
> TFS holds file version history via registered changesets and associated WorkItems. This exact information will be used for generating release notes. Configuration / Release manager can either use system data fields or custom fields for the purpose of generating release notes contents. Powerful XSLT 2.0 support for transforming data from raw XML format is provided out of the box which certainly opens up possibility to generate data in various formats. Support for XSLT 2.0 makes it very easy to apply filtering conditions for transformations output as required by the users.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem recently and enhanced an existing maven plugin to do this.

If you use Git for source control and build your project using Maven, then this may be a good solution:
https://github.com/pankajtandon/maven-git-commit-id-plugin#releasenotes